# javascript: Extract array index from complicated id string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

For example, the id is

```
id='_group[3].id.memberid'
```

I try to extract the '3' using

```
var thisIndex = j(this).attr('id').match('/[\d]+/g')[0];
```

Doesn't work....

Comment: Do you have access to how the HTML is generated?  If so, you might want to put that index into a `data-` attribute instead. Much easier to extract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regexp should be slightly different:

```
.match(/\[(\d+)\]/)[1];
```

- you don't need quotes around regexp
- you have to escape square brackets

Or `split` solution:

```
.split(/\]|\[/)[1];
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/Q5bMP/

Answer (score 5):

If `id='_group[3].id.memberid'` is the standard format, you can do

```
id.split(']')[0].split('[')[1]
```

Comment: @BradM the argument for not using a regex tends to be performance, but I don't think that the chained split call is more performant than the match in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Just to offer an alternative approach, which doesn't answer the question exactly, but might solve the problem in the first place.

If you can alter the HTML, I would do the following:

HTML

```
<div id="_group[3].id.memberid" data-id="3"></div>
```

JS:

```
var thisIndex = j(this).attr('data-id');
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex literal should not be in a string.  Remove the apostrophes inside of the `.match` call.

The `[]` are not necessary if you intend them as a character class; just `\d+` would be enough.  If you intend for them to be literal, you need to escape them:

```
/\[\d+\]/
```

I doubt the `g` is desirable either.

Comment: And if only the first value is to be used, then the `g` is useless.